# Knockout js doesn't apply

Tags: html, input, knockout.js, observable

Beginner here and trying to run Knockout js.
Using debian 10.

What I did:
-installed Knockoutjs (bower install knockout)
-used Knockout on visual studio code

My Code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Knockout Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

    <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

    <button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.5.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function AppViewModel() {

        this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
        /*
        this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
        }, this);

        this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
            var currentVal = this.lastName();        // Read the current value
            this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase()); // Write back a modified value
        };*/
    }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what i get:
[image: My testsite]

Comment: You need to bind an instance of the constructor function to the DOM: `ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel())`

Answer (score 0):

Building on @adiga's comment and making it a working example, this is basically what you are after.

```js
function AppViewModel() {

  this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);

  this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
    var currentVal = this.lastName(); // Read the current value
    this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase()); // Write back a modified value
  };
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

<button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>
```